# How to display two different arrays in a single table in parallel like Left and Right in Php

Tags: php, html, arrays, yii2

I've 2 array $expense and $income.

**Income array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [head] => chitty_installment
            [amount] => 500.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [head] => sales
            [amount] => 100000.00
        )

)
```

**Expense Array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [head] => purchase
            [amount] => 2000.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [head] => sales-return
            [amount] => 9000.00
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [head] => salary 
            [amount] => 11000.00
        )

)
```

I'm trying to print these details like Expense in Left side And Income In Right side of a table
That is The table looks like,

| Expense | Amount | Income | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| purchase | 2000.00 | chitty_installment | 500.00 |
| sales-return | 9000.00 | sales | 100000.00 |
| salary | 11000.00 |  |  |

```
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><b>EXPENDITURE</b></th>
                <th><b>AMOUNT</b></th>
                <th><b>INCOME</b></th>
                <th><b>AMOUNT</b></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($expense as $exp) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $exp['head']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $exp['amount']; ?></td>
            <?php foreach ($income as $inc) { ?>
    
                <td><?php echo $inc['head']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $inc['amount'] ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php }
                } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: you need some code to start off. i'd suggest it'll be too much work to make it from left top down row format using table tags, you're better off using divs and css

Comment: Is there _any_ correlation between the data from the first and the second array here? Or do you just want to output them next to each other, in order? The latter can easily be achieved by checking which of the arrays has more items, and then using a simple `for` loop. If an entry in either array exists for the current loop counter value, you output it, otherwise you output just an empty `td` element.

Comment: There is no connection between the left and right ,I just want output them in to a table structure

Comment: Then the process I just outlined should work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need of second `foreach()`, use first `foreach()` keys to get value from `income array`

Also use `isset()` to check value in `income array` exist for corresponding key or not?

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><b>EXPENDITURE</b></th>
            <th><b>AMOUNT</b></th>
            <th><b>INCOME</b></th>
            <th><b>AMOUNT</b></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($expense as $key=>$exp) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $exp['head']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $exp['amount']; ?></td>
    
                <td><?php echo isset($income[$key]['head']) ? $income[$key]['head'] : ''; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo isset($income[$key]['amount']) ? $income[$key]['amount'] : ''; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can use `MultipleIterator` two loop both array in a single `foreach`.

Just add the flag `MultipleIterator::MIT_NEED_ANY` so that you don't have to worry if the array one has more count than array two or the other way around.

```
$it = new MultipleIterator(MultipleIterator::MIT_NEED_ANY);
$it->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($expense));
$it->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($income));
```

Then just load it in the `foreach` as usual. Index zero denotes as `expense` and `1` as `income`:

```
<?php foreach ($it as $k => $v) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $v[0]['head'] ?? ''; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $v[0]['amount'] ?? ''; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $v[1]['head'] ?? ''; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $v[1]['amount'] ?? ''; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

[Sample output](https://www.tehplayground.com/Le0st98jWbhhnBeM)